Using Kotlin reflection, how do I set a Kotlin Object's member property?
I'm trying to use reflection to set a Kotlin Object's val property.  When I try the code below, I get an exception:
Can not set static final Foo field Person.foo to Biz
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final Foo field Person.foo to Biz
interface Foo {
    fun hello(): String
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override fun hello(): String {
        return "Bar"
    }
}

class Biz: Foo {
    override fun hello(): String {
        return "Biz"
    }
}

object Person {
    val foo: Foo = Bar()
}

fun main() {
    val person = Person
    val property = person::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == "foo" }
    val javaField = property.javaField!!
    javaField.isAccessible = true
    javaField.set(person, Biz()) // exception happens here
    println(Person.foo.hello())
}

Is there any way to have Person.foo.hello() return "Biz" instead of "Bar" via Kotlin or Java reflection APIs?
Thanks!

Unfortunately, the backing fields of vals in an object get compiled to a static final field in the class file. Such fields are very hard to change. See this post for ways of doing this in Java. With each JVM version, this becomes harder and harder to do, and I have yet to find a solution that works for Java 22.
Here is a Kotlin translation of this answer from the linked question. This works until Java 16.
fun main() {
    val person = Person
    val property = person::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == "foo" }
    val javaField = property.javaField!!
    javaField.setFieldAccessible()
    javaField.set(person, Biz()) // or javaField.set(null, Biz()), since the field is static
    println(Person.foo.hello())
}

fun Field.setFieldAccessible() {
    setAccessible(true)

    val lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field::class.java, MethodHandles.lookup())
    val modifiersHandle = lookup.findVarHandle(Field::class.java, "modifiers", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)
    val mods: Int = modifiers

    if (Modifier.isFinal(mods)) {
        modifiersHandle.set(this, mods and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
    }
}


Seems like what I'm trying to do isn't actually going to work.  Thanks for the answer though.  Much appreciated!

One option would be using Unsafe
fun main() {
    val unsafeField = Unsafe::class.java.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe")
    unsafeField.isAccessible = true
    val unsafe = unsafeField.get(null) as Unsafe

    val field = Person.javaClass.getDeclaredField("foo") // <-- FIELD WE WANT TO CHANGE
    
    val base = unsafe.staticFieldBase(field)
    val offset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(field)

    unsafe.putObject(base, offset, Biz()) // <-- REPLACE

    println(Person.foo.hello())
}

